# How can I make As.formula work with a loop?

Tags: r

I have a similar problem to other posts in this forum and I tried the approach suggested elsewhere but I am not sure it is applicable to my case, given that I am not using "least.significant". My code is

```
for(i in 1:length(YVAR)){
for(i in 1:length(YVARCONTROL)){
regression[[i]] <- ivprobit(as.formula(paste(YVAR[[i]] ~ YVARCONTROL[[i]] + CONTROL1 + CONTROL2 + CONTROL3 + CONTROL4 + CONTROL5 + CONTROL6|XVAR|INSTRUMENT)), data=finaldata)
}
}
```

How could I adapt the as.formula in this case so I stop getting the error "Error in class(ff) <- "formula" : attempt to set an attribute on NULL"?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried **without** `formula` and `paste`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stuff inside `as.formula` needs to be a proper string. So this should work (not tested due to lack of example data):

```
for(i in 1:length(YVAR)){
  for(i in 1:length(YVARCONTROL)){
    regression[[i]] <- ivprobit(as.formula(paste(YVAR[[i]],  "~", YVARCONTROL[[i]], "+ CONTROL1 + CONTROL2 + CONTROL3 + CONTROL4 + CONTROL5 + CONTROL6|XVAR|INSTRUMENT")), data=finaldata)
  }
}
```

Comment: Great thank you very much this seems to work, but now it  is telling me "Error in chol.default(mat) : 
  the leading minor of order 4 is not positive definite", is that normal?

Comment: I've never used `ivprobit` so I wouldn't know. Seems to me that this is a different issue from the question posted. You can accept my answer if it worked and ask a new question with a simplified example (just one iteration that produces the error). I'm sure lots of people know more about that command!